# create exe with admin rights with InstallShield in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, administrator

I would like to create my setup to install my application developed in VS 2012. The application needs to be installed in Program Files folder, so it needs to always run with administrator rights. I have created a new InstallShield project inside my solution, but I don't know if it is possible to set some settings to allow that exe always runs as administrator.

I'm using the InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition

Comment: _"I don't know if it is possible to set some settings to allow that exe always runs as administrator"_ Without asking the user for permission? That would seem like a big security flaw if you ask me.

Comment: uhm...maybe you are right Michael...so the only way is that user effectively runs application as administrator...

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. When you say "it needs [...] administrator rights", is "it" the setup or the application? If the latter, what about your application requires administrative privileges - is it modifying files in its install location?

Answer (score 0):

You can only manifest an EXE to indicate to Windows that the EXE requires administrative privs.  You can't simply bypass windows security.